# How to stop background sound (swift3)

Tags: ios, session, swift3, avplayer, audio-player

I used the function `slowPlay` to create an action that will play background music. I tried to do the reverse in `stop` to stop the music. But the music does not stop.

I just want to have a button that plays the music and stops the music. I'm using the code:

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
     slowPlay
}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
     slowStop
}

func slowPlay() {
     do {
          let ap = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slowslow", ofType: "mp3")
          try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ap!) as URL)
     } catch {
          ////
     }

     let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
     do {
          try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
     } catch {

     }
     player?.play()
}

func slowStop() {
     do {
          let ap = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slowslow", ofType: "mp3")
          try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ap!) as URL)
     } catch {
          ////
     }

     let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
     do {
          try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
     } catch {

     }
     player?.stop()
}
```

Comment: please try using single instance of player to play & stop media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your code example you are creating a new instance of the `player` for both play and stop.

You need to create a class variable for your player, something like:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
```

This will allow you to stop like this:

```
func slowStop() {
   player?.stop()
}
```

Comment: If you need a code example for the whole piece let me know, I am not on my computer at the moment. But you should be able to work it out from this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single instance for player like blow

```
 var player: AVAudioPlayer?

 func slowPlay() {
        do {
            let ap = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slowslow", ofType: "mp3")
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ap!) as URL)
        } catch {
            ////
        }

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch {
            //catch error here
        }
        self.player?.play()
    }

    func slowStop() {
        self.player?.stop()
    }
```

You can add validation to check whether  player is valid or not before performing any action.

Comment: Basically what I said with the code example, wanted Sam to work it out ;) This question is something I would believe is from a beginner coder, to my answer was to point him in the right direction but not spoon feed the solution. We were all there once ;)